# Laravel + PHP. Creación de admin en las factorias

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy intentando crear en mi base de datos, dentro de una tabla, a través de una factoría un usuario de tipo 'admin' con unos valores para ciertos campos predeterminados, quedando mi archivo 'DatabaseSeeder.php' de la siguiente manera:

```
public function run()
{
    // $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
        factory(\App\bank_entity::class, 20)->create();
        factory(\App\delivery_terms::class, 20)->create();
        factory(\App\payment_terms::class, 20)->create();
        factory(\App\discount::class, 20)->create();
        factory(\App\transports::class, 20)->create();
        factory(\App\companies::class, 20)->create();
        factory(\App\users::class, 20)->create();
        factory(\App\users::class)->create()(
            ['email'=>'admin@admin.com'],
            ['password'=>'12345678'],
            ['actived'=>1],
            ['email_confirmed'=>1]
        );
}
```

}

Me crea 21 registros en la base de datos, pero ninguno como administrador... al hacer las factorías me da este error en consola :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me crea las factorias en la base de datos !!!
Espero que me podáis ayudar, muchas gracias !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en el `namespace` de los **modelos** que estás mandando a llamar.
Todos los **modelos** están dentro de la carpeta `Models` que está dentro de la carpeta `app`.
Si tu objetivo es crear un usuario de tipo admin, en lugar de usar `factory` usa el método `create` del modelo `users`.

```php-template
use App\Models\bank_entity;
use App\Models\delivery_terms;
use App\Models\payment_terms;
use App\Models\discount;
use App\Models\transports;
use App\Models\companies;
use App\Models\users;

Class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        bank_entity::factory()->count(20)->create();
        delivery_terms::factory()->count(20)->create();
        payment_terms::factory()->count(20)->create();
        discount::factory()->count(20)->create();
        transports::factory()->count(20)->create();
        companies::factory()->count(20)->create();
        users::factory()->count(20)->create();
        users::create([
            'email'=>'admin@admin.com',
            'password'=>'12345678',
            'actived'=>1,
            'email_confirmed'=>1
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Me di cuenta del fallo !!!! Muchas gracias !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!